# Цикличная анимация работает только на одном префабе

Tags: unity3d

В Animator записал цикличную анимацию, и сам Animator затолкал в префаб. На сцене я ставлю все 7 таких префабов (клонов), при нажатии кнопки происходит цикличное вращение объекта, но анимация проигрывается только на каком-то одном объекте из 7. Я так понимаю анимация не может работать на многих префабах (или ошибаюсь?). Мне надо чтобы вращение было на всех объектах одновременно. Можно как то сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Анимация спокойно работает где и на чем угодно.
`AnimatorController` - это ассет отвечающий за само управление анимациями объекта. Он нужен один и настраивается один раз.
`Animator` - это компонент, который отвечает за запуск анимации в `AnimatorController` применительно к конкретному объекту. У каждого объекта этот компонент свой. Недостаточно сказать Play или что вы там делаете одному `Animator`-у, нужно сказать это `Animator`-у каждого объекта.